# Running services (upstart/init.d) in a container

Tags: docker, init, upstart

I'm trying to launch a system in docker that has many init and upstart services and I get this error.

```
initctl: Unable to connect to Upstart:
Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
```

All the workarounds suggest making a hard link to /bin/true to silence the error. But I need to have these services managed by upstart for restart-ability and for upstart emit events to work...

As it seems docker does not support this, I'm considering the gross hack of writing a script to launch all the services in /etc/rcX.d and keep track of the PIDs. That doesn't solve lack of emit events from upstart.

Any other ideas how to launch upstart processes in docker?

Comment: The philosophy of docker is to run a process, if you want to run several, have a look at supervisor https://docs.docker.com/articles/using_supervisord/

Comment: supervisor seems mostly equivalent, if not a subset, of upstart, but thanks for the pointer; it might have to do. Given a large legacy system of init scripts, it's not ideal to convert them over and not doable to run them as individual dockers.

Answer (score 12):

Unfortunately, upstart does not work inside of a docker container because they do some magic with the init system.

This [issue](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/11118) explains:

> If your application uses upstart, this wont fit well in bare docker images, and even more if they divert /sbin/init or
>   /sbin/initctl to something like /bin/true or /dev/null.
>       You application may use service to start if this one has an old school systemV initscript and if the initctl command has not been
>   diverted.
>
> In the case of salt-minion, on ubuntu the packaging uses an upstart
>   job and no classical init script so it is normal that it wont start in
>   both cases.

And [this one](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/1024) says:

> Because Docker replaces the default /sbin/init with its own, there's
>   no way to run the Upstart init inside a Docker container.

Answer (score 3):

You should definitely be able to do that. It's really not the way "Docker Way" but it's very possible. You might want to consider simply using the [phusion/baseimage](https://github.com/phusion/baseimage-docker) base image, it's got support for `runit` built in. If you'd rather use `upstart` just look at how they've implemented the entrypoint, `/sbin/myinit`, and follow that.