# Installing chef server in Centos 6.6 docker container

Tags: docker, chef-infra, centos6

I am running centos 6.5 minimal with the latest version of docker.  I created a container from a centos 6.6 image and that is running fine.  I then installed chef server 12 onto the container but when i run reconfigure it errors out:

```
[2015-03-06T01:32:47+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
Running handlers complete
[2015-03-06T01:32:47+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2015-03-06T01:32:47+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /opt/opscode/embedded/cookbooks/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
Chef Client failed. 13 resources updated in 89.75134466 seconds
[2015-03-06T01:32:49+00:00] FATAL: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: execute[initctl status private-chef-runsvdir] (enterprise::runit_upstart line 34) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
---- Begin output of initctl status private-chef-runsvdir ----
STDOUT:
STDERR: initctl: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
---- End output of initctl status private-chef-runsvdir ----
Ran initctl status private-chef-runsvdir returned 1
```

There seems to be a fix for Ubuntu for this but I was wondering if there is a workaround for Centos since I do see a chef server image available for pull in the docker library so I know that installing it on a container is possible but I haven't been able to get that working for me either.

Comment: After a few research it seems to be docker related. I found [this](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/1024) and [this](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/9403) and [this SO question too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28055715/running-services-upstart-init-d-in-a-container) (doesn't really answer your question at all, but gives clues)

Answer (score 0):

You should start the container with the command : `/sbin/init`. Because the chef server start with daemon, so the PID 1 process must be `/sbin/init`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Backup the existing /sbin/initctl `sudo mv /sbin/initctl /sbin/initctl.distrib`
2. Create a symbolic link for /sbin/initctl from /bin/true `sudo ln -s /bin/true /sbin/initctl`

This should fix the issue